# How to expand multiple sections with one link using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still very inexperienced with HTML and jQuery so I apologise in advance for the probably stupid question, but I haven't found any information on this online.
I am trying to use HTML, CSS and jQuery to achieve expandable sections when clicking on more/less. I have two sections and I want them both to expand when clicking on any more button, independent of which side (otherwise it expands non-symmetrically).

[This is what it looks before clicking on the expand button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GUkE.png)

[This is what I have achieved so far, but it is wrong. When clicking on the more only one section expands.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vzgY.png)

[This is what I am trying to achieve: when clicking on the more link (doesn't matter which one), both sides should expand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtDi1.png)

For this I am using the following code:

```
<div class="expandbox-top" style="height: 280px;" id="expandables">

    <div class="col">
    <p><span class="CCspace">&nbsp;</span><h2>Why?</h2><br>
        <div class="more">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet tortor ac nunc.
        Nulla risus nulla, suscipit eget, rhoncus et, nonummy sed, tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam consequat imperdiet lorem. 
        Nullam aliquet volutpat wisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed dolor
        pede, tempus non, volutpat dignissim, cursus non, mauris. In tristique. Integer blandit, lorem eget tincidunt posuere, quam 
        wisi fermentum elit, quis aliquam ante enim at nibh. Sed faucibus sem et mi. Donec iaculis nulla nec urna. Phasellus ultricies est et urna.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet tortor ac nunc.
        Nulla risus nulla, suscipit eget, rhoncus et, nonummy sed, tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="col">
    <p><span class="CCpullout"><span><img src="images/understand/framework_overview.png" style="margin-top: 90px;" width=280px alt="" /></span></span> 
        <h2>What?</h2><br>
    <div class="more">Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam tristique arcu vitae dui. Ut tempus wisi eget urna. Nullam laoreet scelerisque 
        felis. Aliquam turpis libero, iaculis nec, porta nec, condimentum sit amet, dolor. Proin cursus orci eu purus. 
        In quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
        Phasellus accumsan, augue vitae vehicula viverra, risus velit consequat nunc, ut molestie erat risus non dui. 
        Morbi placerat leo. Maecenas iaculis elit at eros. Cras sem. Phasellus augue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam laoreet tortor ac nunc.
        Nulla risus nulla, suscipit eget, rhoncus et, nonummy sed, tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
  </div>
    </div>
```

With the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Configure/customize these variables.
var showChar = 350;  // How many characters are shown by default
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";


$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
        $('#expandables').animate({height:'300px'}, 400);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
        $("less").css("display", "inline");
        $('#expandables').animate({height:'500px'}, 400);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a trailing `</p>` tag in your last paragraph. Can you also include the css?

Comment: Please update your provided code. Most of the classes/ids you use in your jquery functions aren't present in the html part. Class ".morelink" and id "#expandables" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your `$(".morelink").click(function(){...});` change all `$(this)` to be `$(".morelink")` instead. The scope of `$(this)` is for the clicking item, whereas `$(".morelink")` should select all the items that has the same class.

```
$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(".morelink").hasClass("less")) {
        $(".morelink").removeClass("less");
        $(".morelink").html(moretext);
        $('#expandables').animate({height:'300px'}, 400);
    } else {
        $(".morelink").addClass("less");
        $(".morelink").html(lesstext);
        $("less").css("display", "inline");
        $('#expandables').animate({height:'500px'}, 400);
    }
    $(".morelink").parent().prev().toggle();
    $(".morelink").prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try follow the next fiddle...

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  var whyContent = $('#why p').text();
  var whatContent = $('#what p').text();
  var whySub = whyContent.substring(0, 100);
  var whatSub = whatContent.substring(0, 100);

  $('#why p').text(whySub );
  $('#what p').text(whatSub );

  $('div .content a').on('click', function(e){
    var div = $(e.target).parent('div');
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('less')){
        if(div.attr('id') == 'why'){
           $('#' + div.attr('id') + ' p').text(whyContent);
        }else{
           $('#' + div.attr('id') + ' p').text(whatContent);
        }
        $(e.target).addClass('less');
        div.animate({height:'300px'}, 400);
        $(e.target).text('less');
    }else{
        $(e.target).removeClass('less');
        if(div.attr('id') == 'why'){
          $('#' + div.attr('id') + ' p').text(whySub);
        }else{
          $('#' + div.attr('id') + ' p').text(whatSub);
        }
        div.animate({height:'300px'}, 400);
        $(e.target).text('more');
    }
  });
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sf5dv3vx/7/)

I hope this useful